# mx.viz.plot_network, cannot plot resnet

Tags: python-2.7, plot, mxnet, resnet

guys, I download resnet-152 from this url: http://data.mxnet.io/models/imagenet-11k/resnet-152/

Then, I try to plot this resnet with 152 layers in this way:

```
import mxnet as mx 

sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint('resnet-152', 0)
pltn = mx.viz.plot_network(sym, shape = {'data': (1, 3, 224, 224)}, \
node_attrs = {'shape': 'oval', 'fixedsize': 'false'})
pltn.view('resnet-152')
```

However, the output pdf file is empty. I can plot LeNet, AlexNet and VGG, but what's wrong with the resnet? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Generates a 150k PDF, so it's not huge.  Are you sure the PDF is actually blank?  The upper-left part of the image (likely default view) is all white, because the giant network gets rendered from bottom-left to top-right of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much. It has some relationship with "save_format". If I set save_format = 'eps', I can see the plot. However, the plot just shows part of the network, maybe it's because the network is too large. Can you see the whole neural network? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the code as written works with MXNet 1.1.0 and outputs a PDF that contains a graph for the whole neural network.